# Typescript inheritance from the Tree class (access to properties of parent element)

Tags: typescript, inheritance, casting, tree, typescript-generics

I want to make a convenient and beautiful (strongly typed) inheritance from the Tree class so that I don't have to cast the "parent" property of Tree to the desired type using the "as" service word

```
class Tree{
    protected _parent?:Tree;
    private children:Array<Tree> = [];
    addChild(child: Tree){
        child._parent=this;
        this.children.push(child);
    }
    get parent():Tree|undefined {
        return this._parent;
    }
}
class MyClass extends Tree{
    width:number = 10;
    height:number = 10;
}
var mc1:MyClass = new MyClass();
var mc2:MyClass = new MyClass();
mc1.addChild(mc2);
console.log((mc2.parent as MyClass).height); // Works
console.log(mc2.parent?.height); // Error:  Property 'height' does not exist on type 'Tree'
```

sandbox on [typescriptland.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=37&pln=20&pc=117#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOBTRBvAUASAA7wPYBdFhCATaAfSzCQDt8B+ALgWQG5McBLANzEOmAALTiBK1GAQXjwwATwA8LRAD5oAXmgBtALrsMYEiQDCw0QAohIkozhJEASnQYMl0QDpK1RHTX5hEPQw-Tgg3VzFvNywAVwhBC1MSez0AX0wAc0R8aCpafDN7ZjsAH2iaEkQAM04aRDInDCR8aPgaaGDQzzzUtDTQSBgAWVkjcChoRAAPQnKYJScAd04SP0YaaIBbACNEeHVoAEYABj1BRE50wXw1zZ29jWP2NN49jeADxmHRgf3ahegvmMIAV2C9oG8AEyfEZA36If6AgYgtBvA5uAzGRJmSHJNDAXA0CC4ECINwgXDpMzY4AQqJeOjQSAAmEDexuM4XK7JaAAeh50AA6rh4ABrCB4glEklkinU2m5bwMdnnS74bl8wXCsXQGrQCBgcpbXCTaBbaLZQRMgCi0mFNmgAAU8FhdvhZNAAOQc1Ue6AkXCIGA0AgTSYhbIE9qyF2epQeoA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the polymorphic `this` type in the class for `parent` and `children` instead the `Tree` class:

```
class Tree {
    protected _parent?: this;
    private children: Array<this> = [];
    addChild(child: this) {
        child._parent = this;
        this.children.push(child);
    }
    get parent(): this | undefined {
        return this._parent;
    }
}
class MyClass extends Tree {
    width: number = 10;
    height: number = 10;
}
var mc1: MyClass = new MyClass();
var mc2: MyClass = new MyClass();
mc1.addChild(mc2);
console.log((mc2.parent as MyClass).height); // Works
console.log(mc2.parent?.height); // ok now
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOBTR0DeAoAkAB3gewBdFgiATaAfWzCQDsCB+ALmgIAsBLCAbi1w4BuYItGCcQpOiwCC8eGACeAHnZcAfNAC80ANoBdXpjClSAYXGkAFGI4SWqiAEo0WTDYkA6KjUT0trTh5XBw93SV8PbABXCDZrC0dDAF8sAHNEAmhqOgJLR3tA6AAfaCjaUkQAMw5aRHIMTEwkAij4WgCuL2zfAmT0FNBIGABZBVNwKGhEAA8icpgEZBdMAHcOUnYWWiiAWwAjRHh-AEYABkM2RA5UtgIt3YOj7TPeFKEjneBjllHxof9aitoL8JhA8rx3tBPgAmH5jUEAxBAkFDcHoT7HDzGMwWSwwxLoYB4WgQPAgRAeEB4VKWPHAaGRHx+SDA+FDRweS7XW6JaAAej50AA6nh4ABrCCE4mk8mU6l0hndegMTlXG4EXkC6AAeTF0FoeBWQA)